# How can I find a div element with style?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I find a div element by its style?

I "view source" in IE6 and have this:

```
...an><div id="lga" style="height:231px;margin-top:-22px"><img alt="Google"...
```

How can I get this in JavaScript?

Comment: You are trying to search for a div element based on it's style? Are you seriously using IE6 still?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to find element by its style (I not recommended)

via jQuery do this

```
// jQuery attr equal value selector [1]
$('[style="{your_style_value}"]'); 

// in your case
$('[style="height:231px;margin-top:-22px"]')
```

[1] http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't very clear. Is this what you're looking for?

```
var div_style = document.getElementById('lga').style;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to get the div by its style? It's much simpler to get it by its ID.

Standard JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("lga");
```

If using jQuery:

```
$("#lga");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)

```
document.getElementById("lga");
```

Answer (score 0):

The real WTF is that you are using Internet explorer 6 even though internet explorer 8 is the standard for windows 7, internet explorer 9 and above for 9, and even if you have an old version of windows there is still firefox and Chrome which is > Internet explorer 6.